# How would I convert this table's 'valid' to a date and time in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file with METAR (weather) data. This data is recorded at an uneven interval. I'm trying to use matplotlib to make some graphs from this data. I think to do that I need to use the txt file's 'valid' time in UTC. So how would I go about indexing my pandas dataframe by the valid time and have it recognize it as the date and time in UTC?

I've tried parsing by date, but I don't think this would be the correct approach.

```
KORD = pd.read_table('ORD.txt',parse_dates=['valid'], delimiter=',', index_col=1)
```

## ORD.txt looks like:

```
station,valid,tmpf,dwpf,relh,drct,sknt,p01i,alti,mslp,vsby,gust,skyc1,skyc2,skyc3,skyc4,skyl1,skyl2,skyl3,skyl4,wxcodes,ice_accretion_1hr,ice_accretion_3hr,ice_accretion_6hr,peak_wind_gust,peak_wind_drct,peak_wind_time,feel,metar
ORD,2011-01-30 00:51,32.00,24.08,72.24,0.00,0.00,null,30.05,1018.20,10.00,null,BKN,OVC,null,null,3800.00,5000.00,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,32.00,KORD 300051Z 00000KT 10SM BKN038 OVC050 00/M04 A3005 RMK AO2 SLP182 T00001044
ORD,2011-01-30
```

I have a data frame where the index is by date, but I'm not sure it's by date and time in UTC.

## The output looks like:

```
    station tmpf    dwpf    relh    drct    sknt    p01i    alti    mslp    vsby    ... skyl4   wxcodes ice_accretion_1hr   ice_accretion_3hr   ice_accretion_6hr   peak_wind_gust  peak_wind_drct  peak_wind_time  feel    metar
valid                                                                                   
2011-01-30 00:51    ORD 32.00   24.08   72.24   0.0 0.0 null    30.05   1018.20 10.0    ... null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    32.00   KORD 300051Z 00000KT 10SM BKN038 OVC050 00/M04...
2011-01-30 01:51    ORD 30.92   24.98   78.35   260.0   4.0 0.00    30.04   1018.10 10.0    ... null    null    null    null    null    null    null    null    26.16   KORD 300151Z 26004KT 10SM BKN070 OVC095
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I have understand your question correctly. You can read the data and use default datatime conversion.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("datalake/ORD.txt", sep=',')    
data["valid"] = pd.to_datetime(data.valid, errors='coerce')
data = data.dropna(subset=["valid"])
data = data.set_index("valid")
```

Output of valid column:

```
data.index
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-30 00:51:00', '2011-01-30 00:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]' ...
```

So by default it converts to datetime 64 format for each rows.

Comment: I got an error when running the DatetimeIndec([.... saying name DatetimeIndex is not defined. Is there something I haven't imported or am I calling the wrong thing?

Comment: Hi, try to set the index as `data.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(data['valid']))` and drop the column from the actual dataframe. But definitely it should not be any import issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `valid` column is already in UTC, so there is no need to convert it.

Look at the source row you provided.
It contains `2011-01-30 00:51` as `valid` column.

Then look at the start of METAR data: `KORD 300051Z`.

`KORD` is the aerodrome code and `300051Z` contains:

- `30` - day of month,
- `0051` - hour and minute,
- `Z` - Zulu.

So the hour / minute part in both `valid` column and the METAR data segment
described above are equal.

Note also `parse_dates=['valid']` and `index_col=1` in your code sample.

They mean that:

- `valid` column should be converted to *DateTime* (so the type is right).
- Column No 1 (numeration starts from 0, so the column in question
  is `valid`) should be the **index** column.

And the output you provided confirms what I wrote above:

- The first row (*station*, *tmpf*, ...) contains names of "regular" columns.
- The next row contains just `valid` - the name of **index** column.